# Sharepoint Site I can't add an existing group form

Tags: forms, sharepoint

I created a SharePOint site, and I want to add an existing group form I created. However, when I click edit in my Sharepoint and then clikc the "+" sign to add "Forms" and paste the form URL I get an invalid ID error.

The reason I want to do this is because there'll be 2 others administrators who can view the form results and it seems the only way to let them view the form responses is to create a "group" form.

Thanks,
Mike

I pasted the group form URL and receive an error.

Comment: Is your site a team site connected with M365 group? Did you create a group form for another M365 group or same group?